# What is event sourcing? Why is it named so?

Tags: apache-kafka, event-sourcing, apache-kafka-streams

I read about it in https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html. I know about maintaining change log and its compaction and other things, but never got to understand why it was called Event Sourcing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the journal of events is the source of truth. In other words the  state of the application is sourced from the events.

Answer (score 1):

As the selected answer says, event sourcing is a persistence mechanism where the application state is not stored, but infered out of the historic of events.

In other words, the only source of truth is the event log. Every mutation in the application is stored as an event, in order, within a stream at an event store.

By the way, you've tagged the question with Kafka, but Kafka is not designed to be used for Event Sourcing but for publish-consumer message communication. Although you could in theory persist events forever in kafka and subscribe to streams in order to replay them and project them to infer application's state, there are more suited products such as EventStoreDb with concurrency control when writing.

PS: For Spanish speakers I've got an introduction video on event sourcing [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4xTaoMrBVw). For English speakers I recommend the [Event Store blog](https://eventstore.com/blog/convincing-your-cto/)